# Anonymous but not unique hash?

Tags: anonymity

For a website I am creating we have to store a user id for people that do a test without creating a account. The user id has to be the same for the user if he does te the test 2 times but should also be anonymous, by which I mean not retracable to the person. The only purpose for it is that the ID is the same in the export for a user that does the test more than 1 time.

I have tried thinking of a way but can't get my head around it.

Comment: anonymous is easy: don't record personal info - is your problem how to relate one test to another so that they are linked?

Comment: Yes, the only use for storing the number is so that the different tests are linked together.

Comment: give the user a code to enter when they do tests .....

Comment: the problem isn't about the hash, or about anonymity, it's about linking - I'm not sure this is a security problem

Comment: Entering a code is a option but not all users will do that. And this is a problem on how the information stays secure right..

Comment: only indirectly about security - incentivise the use of codes? Link via IP?

Comment: I appreciate your help though. When linking them via IP, you get the test results and the IP of the person when the database is hacked. Which removes the anonymity a bit right?

Comment: IP does not directly affect anonymity, but it is classified as 'personal info' - it depends on the level of anonymity you are looking for - your web server logs will record the IP anyway ....

Comment: Could hash the IP. Maybe salt it with the user-agent, depending on threshold for tampering (someone can change their user agent easily intentionally, but also inadvertently by changing browsers). This way you have a salt that isn't actually stored.
Another request from the same IP and user-agent would produce the same hash, somebody trying to resolve hashes back to IPs would also need to bruteforce the user-agent - and that's if they knew how you were salting.

Comment: @user18519: too complex and it uses identifiable data. Also unnecessary.

Comment: @JulianKnight realistically it's identifiable data that isn't retrievable by an attacker with a DB dump. It doesn't leave a copy of the identifier on the client, doesn't appear as a parameter in future requests, mitigating some of the potential XSS and MiTM risk. I personally wouldn't consider salting and hashing complex at all, but that's really a subjective statement.

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is to generate UUID's on the server and set a cookie. That then becomes the ID and the client manages it without further need of input from the server.

UPDATE: Just to clarify, using this method stores nothing at all about either the user nor the client, it is in no way identifying other than knowing that it is likely the same cookie comes from the same source. Using a UUID ensures, like a hash, that the number is unique without needing any complex algorithms or user information that might compromise identity.

Really not a security question though.

Comment: cookie kind of defeats the appearance of anonymity

Comment: @schroeder: well , kind of, because there is no way to identify the user from the cookie. You only know it is the same browser.

Comment: Actually, unless you include some verification, it is hard to know that it definitely came from the same browser since MitM attacks could spoof that. But I certainly disagree that it defeats anonymity since the cookie doesn't identify the user nor the client, it only contains a random number and one that the user can throw away at any time to get a new one.

Answer (score 1):

> For a website I am creating we have to store a user id for people that do a test without creating a account.

Now hold on right there.  The act of creating an account is, arguably, equivalent to the act of storing a user ID. So unless there is something subtle about this requirement, it is a nonsensical requirement.

Maybe the true requirement is that you must create test accounts that do not link to any actual person.  The solution for this is [anonymization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_anonymization); just create real accounts per your usual process, but use dummy [PII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personally_identifiable_information). If you need a very large number of accounts, you can take a snapshot of actual user data fro your production database, then write a small program to reset their passwords and randomize their names and other sensitive information.